# Infinite coordinate grid

Tags: flutter, maps, cartesian-coordinates

Perhaps such questions have already been asked, but I did not find any specific solution.

I have a need to use maps in Cartesian coordinates (no longitude and latitude, just (x, y))

I need the functionality that is in the flutter_map package to manage the map, as well as additional construction of markers, lines, circles, polygons

Are there any ready-made solutions or suggestions for implementation on how to make an endless canvas with control?

I tried to use flutter_map, but despite the crs settings it still continues to work with longitude and latitude

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.